# Add active class on list item click is not working properly

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a menu with some categories:

```
<div class="col p-0 m-0">
    <ul class="Categories__Menu">
        @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}" href="#">{{$category->name}}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
        <li><a  data-toggle="modal" id="showCategories" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If the user clicks in More it opens a modal with more categories, the modal have this content:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="categoriesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="modal-list row">
                            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <a class="">All categories</a>
                            </li>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <img src="{{ $category->image }}"/>
                                    <a name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some jquery to do an ajax request to get the conferences that belong to the clicked category. This is working fine.

But I want that the clicked category becomes the active in the menu "Categories__Menu". This is working, the clicked category stays active.

But there is one issue. When  a category is clicked in the "Categories__Menu" the list item "More" changes the text to that clicekd category text. Do you know why? The item "More" should only stay with the clicked item text if that clicked item is in the modal not in the menu "Categories__Menu".

fiddle with the issue without the ajax part: https://jsfiddle.net/69LnLa7y/2/

Do you know where is the issue?

```
    $("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){
         alert("test");
  $('#showCategories').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');




  $('#showCategories').addClass('active');


  var category_id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(category_id);


  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');


        $.ajax({

            url: '{{ route('category.conferences',null) }}/' + category_id,
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(result){
                $('#conferences').empty();
                var newConferences='';
                var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
                $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                    var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

                    newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
    '                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
    '                            <img class="card-img-top" src='+ conference.image +' alt="Card image cap">\n' +
    '                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
    '                                <h5 class="card-title">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
    '                            </div>\n' +
    '                    </div></div>';
                });
                $('#conferences').html(newConferneces);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.status)
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`$('#showCategories').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>')`
```

Above line of code causing the "more" text to change it to "category test" as you are setting the html to clicked category.

Comment: Thanks, but the "more" should change to the category text when a category inside the modal is clicked. But it should not change if a category in the "Categories__Menu" is clicked.

Comment: @joW
` if($(this).closest(".modal-list").length) {
   $('#showCategories').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  }`
Use above code.it should work

Comment: Thanks, like that there is only one issue. When a category is clicked in the modal the text "More" changes to the text of the clicked category but it should also change the class to active, do you know how to achieve that? Fiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/69LnLa7y/7/

Comment: @joW Here is the updated fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/69LnLa7y/9/